# SQL Server - Query to return ID's only which have different values per ID in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2016 Enterprise - Let's say I run a query on our main table to bring back all records from ID's 1 through 5. I would get something like this:

```
ID  Status  BatchID
1   Active  493fd8bc
1   Active  493fd8bc
1   Active  493fd8bc
1   Active  493fd8bc
1   Active  493fd8bc
2   Active  2d91c2f2
2   Active  2d91c2f2
3   Active  2a1338ac
3   Active  2a1338ac
3   Active  2a1338ac
4   Active  0c469bcc
4   Active  0c469bcc
4   Active  0c469bcc
4   Active  0c469bcc
4   Active  0c469bcc
4   Active  0c469bcc
4   Active  0c469bcc
5   Active  ca8896bd
5   Active  ca8896bd
5   Active  ca8896bd
```

The above is what we would expect to see, such that each `ID` has the same `BatchID` associated with it (additional columns that differentiate each record are irrelevant to this question).

We've run into some issues where we are seeing this is not the case for all `ID's`.  For example let's say we ran the same query and it returned this instead:

```
ID  Status  BatchID
1   Active  493fd8bc
1   Active  493fd8bc
1   Active  752e8d5d
1   Active  752e8d5d
1   Active  493fd8bc
2   Active  2d91c2f2
2   Active  2d91c2f2
3   Active  f2191595
3   Active  2a1338ac
3   Active  2a1338ac
4   Active  feaf9567
4   Active  f5d64c8c
4   Active  e5eff3a2
4   Active  0c469bcc
4   Active  49e5e2f2
4   Active  0c469bcc
4   Active  e5eff3a2
5   Active  ca8896bd
5   Active  ca8896bd
5   Active  ca8896bd
```

In this case we see that `ID's` 1, 3, and 4's `BatchID` do NOT all match.

If I wanted to run a query on all `ID's` and have it return to me a list of `ID's` whose `BatchID's` do NOT match for all records of that `ID`, how would I accomplish this?

The results would look like this if my table contained only the data in the 2nd example above.

```
ID
1
3
4
```

Alternatively, we'd be just as well-suited if the results were returned as entire records as long as the record contains the `ID`, and there is only one record per `ID`.  The `BatchID` returned is of no consequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use aggregation and count the number of distinct batches for each `ID`:

```
SELECT ID
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT BatchID) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to want the entire row, you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and t2.batchid <> t.batchid
             );
```

If you just want the ids, then Tim's answer is the better approach.